# Solve the Differential equation $x^3 \frac{dy}{dx}=y^3+y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Differential equation $$x^3 \frac{dy}{dx}=y^3+y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

i reduced the equation as

$$x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3\left(1+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2}\right)$$ $\implies$

$$\frac{x^3}{y^3}\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(1+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2}\right) \tag{1}$$ Next put $$\frac{x}{y}=v$$ we get

$$ x=vy$$ then

$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=v+y\frac{dv}{dy}$$ Then $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{v^3}{v+y\frac{dv}{dy}}=1+\sqrt{1+v^2}$$ Reciprocating we get

$$\frac{v+y\frac{dv}{dy}}{v^3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+v^2}+1}$$  Rationalizing RHS we get

$$\frac{v+y\frac{dv}{dy}}{v^3}=\frac{\sqrt{1+v^2}-1}{v^2}$$ Rearranging we get

$$\frac{dv}{v \times \left(\sqrt{1+v^2}-2\right)}=\frac{dy}{y}$$

EDIT: i am posting here the clue given by paul using Substitution $v=\tan z$:

$$\int\frac{dv}{v \times \left(\sqrt{1+v^2}-2\right)}=\int\frac{\sec^2 z\: dz}{\tan z(\sec z-2)}=\int\frac{dz}{\sin z(1-2\cos z)}$$ So

$$\int\frac{dz}{\sin z(1-2\cos z)}=\int \frac{\sin z\: dz}{\sin^2 z(1-2\cos z)}$$

Put $\cos z=t$ and use partial fractions

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot even solve your equation in $v,y$. It can solve the equation in $x,y$, but the solution is ridiculously long. Having said that, the integral in $v$ is fairly simple, a sum of $\log$s

Comment: Hint: use $v=\tan\theta$.

Comment: or  $ \sinh \theta $

Comment: @JohnDoe the asker stated that v = x/y, so it should solve

Comment: @Cursed1701 [Here is what I put into Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+xy%27%3D(sqrt(1%2By%5E2)-2)y). However, seeing that the integral is quite straight forward, I think Wolfram just messed up on that particular example

Answer (score 1):

Well, let $\text{y}\left(x\right)=x\cdot\text{r}\left(x\right)$, which gives $\text{y}'\left(x\right)=x\cdot\text{r}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}\left(x\right)$:

$$x^3\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)=\text{y}\left(x\right)^3+\text{y}\left(x\right)^2\cdot\sqrt{x^2+\text{y}\left(x\right)^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$x^3\cdot\left(x\cdot\text{r}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}\left(x\right)\right)=\left(x\cdot\text{r}\left(x\right)\right)^3+\left(x\cdot\text{r}\left(x\right)\right)^2\cdot\sqrt{x^2+\left(x\cdot\text{r}\left(x\right)\right)^2}\tag1$$

Solve for $\text{r}'\left(x\right)$:

$$\text{r}'\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)^2-1+\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{r}\left(x\right)^2}\right)}{x}\tag2$$

Devide both sides by the numerator of the RHS and integrate both sides:

$$\int\frac{\text{r}'\left(x\right)}{\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)^2-1+\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{r}\left(x\right)^2}\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

For the integrals:

- Substitute $\text{u}=\text{r}\left(x\right)$:
  $$\int\frac{\text{r}'\left(x\right)}{\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)^2-1+\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{r}\left(x\right)^2}\right)}\space\text{d}x=$$
  $$\int\frac{1}{\text{u}\cdot\left(\text{u}^2-1+\text{u}\cdot\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)}\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
  $$\frac{\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2\right|}{3}-\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2-1\right|+\frac{2\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2-3\right|}{3}+\text{C}_1\tag4$$
- $$\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}_2\tag5$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2\right|}{3}-\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2-1\right|+\frac{2\ln\left|\left(\text{u}+\sqrt{1+\text{u}^2}\right)^2-3\right|}{3}=\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\tag6$$.

Now, use:

$$\text{u}=\frac{\text{y}\left(x\right)}{x}\tag7$$

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the ODE is presented below on parametric form. The explicit form can be obtained but involves the roots of a cubic polynomial equation which would lead to a big formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have, $$x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3+y^2\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$$
Put $y=vx$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}+v$

The differential equation then simplifies to;

$$\int\frac{dx}{v^3-v+v^2\sqrt{v^2-1}}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$

Substitute $v=sect$ and $dv=sec(t)tan(t)dt$

$$\int\frac{\sec(t)\tan(t)\,du}{\sec^2(t)-sec(t)+\sec(t)\tan(t)}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\int\frac{\tan(t)\,du}{\sec(t)-1+\tan(t)}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\int\frac{\sin(t)\,du}{1-\cos(t)+\sin(t)}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$

The LHS can be solved using Weierstrass substitution,

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(t\right)-\cos\left(t\right)+1\right)+t+\ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+1\right)}{2}=ln(x)+c$$

Putting back $t=arcsec\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(arcsec\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)-\cos\left(arcsec\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)+1\right)+arcsec\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{arcsec\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{2}\right)+1\right)}{2}=ln(x)+c$$